# NavigationController & hidesBarsOnSwipe with CollectionView subview

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, swift3, xcode8, subview

I'm pretty new to iOS development and I'm having some trouble with navigation controller and a collection view as a Subview.
Ive started my project with a single view application and embedded in a Navigation controller (The Navigation controller root is my ViewController).
Inside my view controller i've added a Collection view with a custom cell (it doesn't take the whole screen).
when I run my application everything works fine.
when I tried to set the method

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

nothing happens inside my Collection view even though I'm scrolling, but if I swipe within the View controller and not the Collection view the method works and the Navigation bar gets hidden just fine.

I want the method to work when I swipe inside the Collection view.

Thank...

Answer (score 0):

If your collection view top is set to the top layout guide top then the view behind is has never scrolled, i.e. your view isn't scrolling so the navigation bar is not hiding.

Try setting your collection view top to the "Top Layout Guide.Top". Try changing this to "Superview.Top".